# dapptools verification: jays: error in -e

Tags: contract-verification, dapptools, seth

I'm deploying a simple blank contract:

```js
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0-or-later
pragma solidity ^0.8.6;

contract DapptoolsPlay {
}
```

However, when I use the `verify` command from dapptools, I run into this issue:

```
$ dapp create DapptoolsPlay --verify
++ seth send --create 6080604052348015600f57600080fd5b50603f80601d6000396000f3fe6080604052600080fdfea2646970667358221220b4af28e7b2f15aab8c9f32be2ea8d08b27e64655e442ed2ea630324e85216f8964736f6c63430008060033 'DapptoolsPlay()'
seth-send: warning: `ETH_GAS' not set; using default gas amount
Ethereum account passphrase (not echoed): seth-send: Published transaction with 92 bytes of calldata.
seth-send: 0x6eeef773154b21cd076a4914cb451e2586ed4494ed1df0b444756d124d3c7763
seth-send: Waiting for transaction receipt.......
seth-send: Transaction included in block 29148035.
Verifying contract at 0x8294a599ccf5ae57fc9ba57461e1d70ee3682a16
jays: error in -e
```

Any idea of what's going on?

I have my `ETHERSCAN_API_KEY` set correctly as an environment variable.